# android tts in service failed to continuously speaking

Tags: android, service, text-to-speech, logcat

In my app, i created an activity. It creates a service at startup. There is a button in activity. When it is pressed, it triggers the service to use TTS to repeat to say a sentence at 10 sec interval. I can hear the sentence repeat. I then pressed home to hide the activity, and then turn off the sreen. I can still hear the sentence. But after about half an hour, i cannot longer hear it. Then i have a look at logcat:

```
06-02 20:56:30.237: W/dalvikvm(32503): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/myact/myservice$2; (84)

06-02 20:56:30.237: W/dalvikvm(32503): Link of class 'Lcom/example/myact/myservice$2;' failed

06-02 20:56:30.237: E/dalvikvm(32503): Could not find class 'com.example.myact.myservice$2', referenced from method com.example.myact.myservice.setTts

06-02 20:56:30.237: W/dalvikvm(32503): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 515 (Lcom/example/myact/myservice$2;) in Lcom/example/myact/myservice;

06-02 20:56:30.237: D/dalvikvm(32503): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0006

06-02 20:56:30.237: D/dalvikvm(32503): VFY: dead code 0x0008-0042 in Lcom/example/myact/myservice;.setTts (Landroid/speech/tts/TextToSpeech;)V

06-02 20:56:30.237: D/dalvikvm(32503): VFY: dead code 0x0044-0065 in Lcom/example/myact/myservice;.setTts (Landroid/speech/tts/TextToSpeech;)V

06-02 20:56:30.247: I/dalvikvm(32503): DexOpt: unable to
 optimize instance field ref 0x001b at 0x4a in Lcom/example/myact/myservice;.setTts

06-02 20:56:30.247: I/dalvikvm(32503): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x001b at 0x58 in Lcom/example/myact/myservice;.setTts
```

Does anyone can explain to me what happened? thanks in advance.

For tts config in serivce:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
    {

        setTts(_tts);

    }       
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setTts(TextToSpeech tts)
{
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15)
    {
        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceId)
            {
                onDoneSpeaking(utteranceId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceId)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart(String utteranceId)
            {
            }
        });                     
    }
    else
    {

        tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
    }
}
```